# When I validate my XML document I keep getting an error

Tags: xml, dtd

When I validate my XML document against my DTD, I keep getting the same error and I can't figure out why its happening, the error simply says: 
Document root-element "Candidate_Profile", must match DOCTYPE root "CV".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE CV [
<!ELEMENT Candidate_Profile (Personal_Details,Employment_History,Qualifications)>
<!ELEMENT Personal_Details (Surname,First_Name,Middle_Name?,Mobile_Phone,Home_Phone,Email,Address,PostCode)>
<!ELEMENT Surname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT First_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Middle_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Mobile_Phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Home_Phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Email (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PostCode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Employment_History (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Qualifications (#PCDATA)> 
]>

<Candidate_Profile>
 <Personal_Details>
   <Surname>Meacham</Surname>
  <First_Name>Sofia</First_Name>
  <Mobile_Phone>077111111</Mobile_Phone>
  <Home_Phone>012222222</Home_Phone>
  <Email>sofia@xxxxxx</Email>
  <Address>Romsey</Address>
  <PostCode>SO</PostCode>
 </Personal_Details>
 <Employment_History>Uni 1, Companies</Employment_History>
 <Qualifications>Several</Qualifications>
 </Candidate_Profile>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the square bracket on the next line?

Comment: And try adding encoding="UTF-8" to the xml tag

Answer (score 0):

Try the two things I mentioned in the comments and then change CV to Candidate Profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE Candidate_Profile 
[
<!ELEMENT Candidate_Profile (Personal_Details,Employment_History,Qualifications)>
<!ELEMENT Personal_Details (Surname,First_Name,Middle_Name?,Mobile_Phone,Home_Phone,Email,Address,PostCode)>
<!ELEMENT Surname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT First_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Middle_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Mobile_Phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Home_Phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Email (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PostCode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Employment_History (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Qualifications (#PCDATA)> 
]>

<Candidate_Profile>
 <Personal_Details>
   <Surname>Meacham</Surname>
  <First_Name>Sofia</First_Name>
  <Mobile_Phone>077111111</Mobile_Phone>
  <Home_Phone>012222222</Home_Phone>
  <Email>sofia@xxxxxx</Email>
  <Address>Romsey</Address>
  <PostCode>SO</PostCode>
 </Personal_Details>
 <Employment_History>Uni 1, Companies</Employment_History>
 <Qualifications>Several</Qualifications>
 </Candidate_Profile>
```

Worth a shot [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp)